# code snippet for getting the y-m-d for the past 30 days - php

Tags: php

Hi i currently have this piece of code,

```
$date = time();
 for ($n = 1; $n <= date('y-m-d', $date); $n++) {
 //Code to run 
}
```

However what I would really like it to do is for $n for today for example would be 2015-01-14 yesterday 2015-01-13 and so on for the past 30 days, so that i can use $n and get the full date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Easiest solution to your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class for this.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$dates = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    $date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $dates[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}

print_r($dates);
```

Which will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-01-13
    [1] => 2015-01-12
    [2] => 2015-01-11
    [...]
    [29] => 2014-12-15
)
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect for what i need

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php    
$d = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) 
$d[] = date("y-m-d", strtotime('-'. $i .' days'));
?>
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the code below

```
<?php
for ($n = 0; $n <= 30; $n++) {

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$n.' days'))."<br>"; // this ill print last 30 days date
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you